# Dataframe throwing 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, How can I fix it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
I have a problem about showing bar graph in pandas. Some rating values cannot be defined because of the result of query shown below. But I want to show all both missing values and defined values in bar plot graph. How can I fix it?
```

Here is my code snippet and results

```
netflix_df.query("type == 'TV Show'")["rating"].value_counts()

TV-14    39
TV-MA    32
TV-PG    14
TV-Y7     6
TV-Y      3
R         1
TV-G      1
```

After I get a results from query, I want to show in bar graph but there is an error here.

```
rating_order =  ['G', 'TV-Y', 'TV-G', 'PG', 'TV-Y7', 'TV-Y7-FV', 'TV-PG', 'PG-13', 'TV-14', 'R', 'NC-17', 'TV-MA']
tv_show_rating = netflix_df.query("type == 'TV Show'")["rating"].value_counts()[rating_order].fillna(0)  <---- HERE IS AN ERROR
rating_barplot(tv_show_rating,'TV Show', 40,'images/image6.png')
```

After I revised this code shown below.

```
rating_order =  ['G', 'TV-Y', 'TV-G', 'PG', 'TV-Y7', 'TV-Y7-FV', 'TV-PG', 'PG-13', 'TV-14', 'R', 'NC-17', 'TV-MA']
tv_show_rating = netflix_df.query("type == 'TV Show'")["rating"].value_counts().reindex([rating_order])
```

The error is defined below.

```
TypeError: ('G',) is not a string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
rating_order =  ['G', 'TV-Y', 'TV-G', 'PG', 'TV-Y7', 'TV-Y7-FV', 'TV-PG', 'PG-13', 'TV-14', 'R', 'NC-17', 'TV-MA']
tv_show_rating = netflix_df.query("type == 'TV Show'")["rating"].value_counts().reindex(rating_order).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Assuming you want to plot a bar graph of the query. You can put the query result into a new dataframe. In this case I have put it in `df`. See `df` below

df

[image]

Try plot as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df.Rating,df.Count)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: question is clear. As you can see , some items resulted from query cannot be included in rating_order list. I want to show all  rating_order including query results and other values cannot be included in bar graph.

Comment: In few words, what are you trying to do in this line of code; tv_show_rating = netflix_df.query("type == 'TV Show'")["rating"].value_counts()[rating_order].fillna(0) ? Is it possible for you to give the original dataset from which the query originates and what your expected output is? Clarity of datascience questions is not decided by the originator but those it is intended for.

Comment: Some items not included in rating_order cannot be filled with 0. The problem is here.

Comment: Please provide original dataframe, you will get help. Just edit question please

Comment: @komatiraju032 Can you show my post if you don't mind

Comment: Sorry @Tony Brand, not ignoring you, ran into urgent tasks at work. Happy to look into your question in more detail once I ease up today